# What are the possible reasons why an instance of an Linux application would start running multiple instances of itself?

Tags: linux, unix

I have got the Linux test with this question. I see the following reasons:
- predicted behavior, like each instance is created for some event;
- unpredictable behavior, some bug.

Any others ideas how I can answer this question?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @val, your question is unclear. Please reformulate it in a comprehensible manner.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what this question's author has in his mind :-) 
Multiple instances (e.g. Apache) can be started to improve performance. In the case of Apache it is mostly limiting latency with new requests, but surely you could find examples on increasing some application's throughput as well. 
 
Another reason may be increasing application's availability, especially if these instances are started on multiple nodes/containers.